# Unable to split a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string, "20160630048|上海11选5|2016-06-30 16:47:52|2.000|前三直选/复式", that I want to split into five strings:

MY CODE :

```
String splitString = Value; 
        String[] arrSplit = splitString.split("|");
        String part1 = arrSplit[0];
        String part2 = arrSplit[1];
        String part3 = arrSplit[2];
        String part4 = arrSplit[3];
        String part5 = arrSplit[4];
```

That means the first string will contain the characters before '|', and the second string will contain the characters after '|' and so on.  Indeed i getting the value was numeric not the string. Kindly advise

Result PrintOut :

```
STRING SPLIT : 2 + 0 + 1 + 6 + 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe since it's a special character used in regular expressions: `|`

```
splitString.split("\\|");
```

---

### [Regex Logical Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> XY X followed by Y
>   **X|Y Either X or Y**
>   (X) X, as a capturing group

Comment: Thanks you , its working .. thanks very much @Yassin Hajaj